# Realtime database event child_added is called with unexpected prevChildKey parameter

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Imagine the following scenario in Realtime Database : there is a list/collection called "posts" and two independent processes are pushing data to those list using realtime database push() mechanism that generates unique timestamp based keys for every child element. Also both of those processes are listening for "child_added" event on "posts" list/collection. In the end "child_added" is called when other process writes data the DB and when current process executes push() - the second case is some kind of local "child_added" event that happens before the data to reach DB server.

What I expect in such a scenario is both processes to receive "child_added" for every pushed data in "posts" lists. Receiving all "child_added" calls and having the key of pushed data and previous child key, every process should be able to create a list of datas ordered by key - that will be the same as data in the DB. But what happens is that when "child_added" is a local event (called when the current process pushes data to the list) the value of the previous child key has unexpected value - that is incorrect.

Here is a node.js sample code:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
const cluster     = require('cluster');
var sleep = require('sleep'); 

var serviceAccount = require("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.json");
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com"
  });

var db = admin.database();
var postsRef = db.ref("posts");

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);

    for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
      cluster.fork();
    }

    doIt();

} else {

    console.log(`Slave ${process.pid} is running`);
    doIt();
}

function doIt(){
    postsRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey) {
        var newPost = snapshot.val();
        console.log("child_added: pid:"+process.pid+" key:"+snapshot.key+" Author: " + newPost.author+" msg: " + newPost.title+"prev_key: " + prevChildKey);
      });


    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var newPostRef = postsRef.push();
        newPostRef.set({
            author: "author "+process.pid,
            title: "message "+i
        });
        sleep.msleep(250)
    }
}
```

The above code produces the following output:

```
child_added: pid:23897 key:-M8j8tZn401z6r95U70Z Author: author 23897 msg: message 1prev_key: -M8j8tVpw0tjciWf2siP
...
child_added: pid:23904 key:-M8j8tZn401z6r95U70Z Author: author 23897 msg: message 1prev_key: -M8j8tXhl8Es5L0aD5Lg
...
```

Since the real key of previous element for -M8j8tZn401z6r95U70Z is -M8j8tXhl8Es5L0aD5Lg (checked the database) the call of child_added for pid: 23897 has wrong value of prevChildKey parameter.

[Here is how data looks in DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYK94.png)